# Communication between applications over local TCP/IP socket

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, ipc

I am developing a fairly complicated application, I will go straight to the setup so I can explain the workflow.

1. Client connecting to a centralised server (monitoring, management and maintaining)
2. Local HTTP Server build with Twisted Framework (Serving 1 configuration web interface, 1 Administration for the device and 1 Operation Interface)
3. Server for executing various commands on the host either from the central server or from the http server (printing, uploading and etc.)
4. *Not Confirmed* GUI application replacing the Operation Interface

I am thinking about building a TCP/IP communication between the processes and clients (probably 2 and 3 will be a server/client hybrid, so to achieve the polling effect and act on data) My questions are:

*Is this the best way to communicate between the apps?*

*Each instance of the application will be used only by a single user, so what will the hardware requirements be if none of the applications is reading/writing large data, only commands, and meta data, because the applications are running on single machine (so have access to the File system and etc.)?*

***INFO:***
The system will run on a Debian Environment, on a low end hardware (1Ghz CPU, 256-512MB RAM or something similar), The application is to be built entirely with Python

Comment: I am aware that this question might get closed as Opinion based/Off topic/Not Constructive

Comment: I've read your question a few times and I'm still confused with the topology. Is the Local HTTP Server the command server or are those two separate entities? How many clients are you expecting to have? What are your expected use cases? And what does "Not Confirmed" mean?

Comment: Not confirmed means that the GUI could replace the web interface. The local HTTP server is different than the command server, the clients on this particular set-up will be up to 1-2 Operating user and in some cases the administrator will be connected to the application (when particular maintenance needs to be performed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [ZeroMQ](http://zeromq.org/)

> ØMQ (also known as ZeroMQ, 0MQ, or zmq) looks like an embeddable
>   networking library but acts like a concurrency framework. It gives you
>   sockets that carry atomic messages across various transports like
>   in-process, inter-process, TCP, and multicast. You can connect sockets
>   N-to-N with patterns like fan-out, pub-sub, task distribution, and
>   request-reply. It's fast enough to be the fabric for clustered
>   products. Its asynchronous I/O model gives you scalable multicore
>   applications, built as asynchronous message-processing tasks. It has a
>   score of language APIs and runs on most operating systems. ØMQ is from
>   iMatix and is LGPLv3 open source.

Comment: I would rather avoid the *MQ approach for what the poster asked [0MQ,AMQP and similar], they introduce great complexity and are good for specific requirements (low latency, high volume of messages, routing,broadcasting ecc...), which I don't really see in the question.